# Gradle configuration takes more than few seconds

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to optimize build process of Android application. It is a multimodule project (63 modules) and pretty much all of them are android-library.

I have tried to comment out everything possible, yet my configuration is stuck at 25 seconds. All internet resources say it should be around 1-2 seconds. (https://youtu.be/sQC9-Rj2yLI?t=1777)

Everything takes 0.001s or a little bit more and then callback which take 0.8 seconds (which is still okay), but **what is "script application"?**

[image]

`./gradlew temp:assembleDebug --scan --no-build-cache --refresh-dependencies --configure-on-demand --daemon`

I have also played with different memory variables in my `gradle.properties` but this number does not get reduced.

Comment: "should be around 1-2 seconds" for a 63 module build? I doubt that.

Comment: yeah, that's the question. I might not understand it correctly. https://youtu.be/sQC9-Rj2yLI?t=1777 They have 100 modules. All of them could be pure java/kotlin modules, but then the number of tasks is too high.

Comment: Ah, you seem to understand correctly. Slight differences could also be caused by things such as an older gradle version and slower hardware. Are you running from an SSD and don't bottleneck the CPU?

Comment: Newest versions of gradle, ssd, 32gb ram, everything should be fine. It is a company project, I am not the only one experiencing it, I am just in charge of doing something about it.